# Reliable PHP who-is method?

Tags: php, whois

I have been using this (http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpwhois/) and it seems to be effective, but I plan to use it on a website that will allow users to enter a domain name and receive the who-is information. Unfortunately, the thing that I linked to and all other scripts return text in the who-is information that says to not use it in a high-trafficking mode. I have seen this on many similar websites as well, so is it a big deal or is there a more-reliable method of obtaining who-is information? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to run a few queries, than you can easily host the whois service yourself because it's likely you will never pass the limits imposed by the whois servers.

If you need to send a large number of queries, then you may want to consider a third party service such as [DomainTools](http://domaintools.com) or [RoboWhois](https://robowhois.com).
These services may use different strategies (such as caching, accreditation, ...) to reduce the risk of being throttled by a whois server.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of RoboWhois.*